# strange python requests message size

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a strange situation where a request with lighter content ends up consuming more bytes than a request with the larger content.

this is my code:

```
import requests
import base64

def do_work(image_raw, image_name):
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

    data = {'pic':image_raw}
    res = requests.post(url, data=data, json={'name':image_name})
    print len(image_raw), len(res.content)

    image_enc = base64.b64encode(image_raw)
    res = requests.post(url=url, json={'pic':image_enc, 'name':image_name})
    print len(image_enc), len(res.content)
```

a typical result is:

> 68166 925208
>
> 90888 182301

the encoded image weighs 33% more than the raw image, which makes perfect sense.
but how come the first request weighs much more?
There must be something wrong in the way i formatted the request.

Comment: there is a typo in `res.content`, please correct and see what you are getting.

Comment: Whoops. (un?)fortunately the typo isn't present in the actual code

Comment: I'm not sure if this explains your problem, but I'm pretty sure that `json` and `data` are exclusive; from [the code](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L444) it looks like the `json` parameter is ignored if `data` is not empty.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right my friend. the first response indeed contains json=null, yet the size issue remains unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm using Python 3, and my `image_raw` is a `byte` object, so the results will be different (probably due to the difference between things like `byte`, `unicode` and `str`), but the explanation should be applicable.

It helps to print out a part of the actual `res.content`. In the first case:

```
>>> res.content[:200]
b'{\n  "args": {}, \n  "data": "", \n  "files": {}, \n  "form": {\n    "pic": "\\ufffdPNG\\r\\n\\u001a\\n\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\rIHDR\\u0000\\u0000\\u0001\\u000f\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0019\\b\\u0002\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\ufffd\\uf'
```

In the second case:

```
>>> res.content[:200]
b'{\n  "args": {}, \n  "data": "", \n  "files": {}, \n  "form": {\n    "name": "1.png", \n    "pic": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQ8AAAAZCAIAAACgtTxbAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAc'
```

As you can see, `res.content`, the string returned by http://httpbin.org/post, is actually a human-readable representation of the POST data. In the first case, the POST data contains many non-ASCII characters, which are encoded in an even more inefficient encoding than base64 -- `\uxxxx` escape sequences. This is why the length of `res.content` is longer in the first case.

Comment: So, even though the response was inflated, the actual HTTP request wasn't? Is there a simple way to verify this, preferably without sniffing?

Comment: Actually, the actual HTTP request seems to be inflated too, but at a different rate since it's a different encoding. You can see this by looking for "Content-Length" in `res.content`. I'm guessing that encoding is just the same encoding you often see in URLs (`pic=%FF%FDPNG%0D%0A`...), but currently I don't have a way to verify this.

Comment: I did notice the Content-Length field, but i thought that it applies to the response which we now know to be inflated, rather than the request

Comment: You can get info about the request with the `request` object, eg `res.request.headers['Content-Length']`

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks! it seems that the actual HTTP request is indeed inflated. maybe I can include a header to deal with the encoding and fix this?

Comment: You could, but i think you should let `requests` handle the headers. In your 1st request you pass a dictionary to the `data` parameter. That form-encodes the items in your dictinary. If you want to send unencoded data you can use a string, eg: `data = "pic="+image_raw`.

Comment: Actually `requests` has an interface to POST files directly: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file.